# Is it possible to restore a core Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I accidentally uninstalled the newsfeed component from my Joomla install.  This apparently breaks the database integrity a little and I want to reinstall.  I was able to do that at least partially using the "Discover" feature, but there are still a few issues.  I get this with a database check:

Table 'sds_newsfeeds' should not have column 'filename'. (From file 3.0.0.sql.)
Table 'sds_newsfeeds' does not have column 'description'. (From file 3.0.0.sql.)
Table 'sds_newsfeeds' does not have column 'version'. (From file 3.0.0.sql.)
Table 'sds_newsfeeds' does not have column 'hits'. (From file 3.0.0.sql.)
Table 'sds_newsfeeds' does not have column 'images'. (From file 3.0.0.sql.)

The component name is com_newsfeed, and the localizations are not set:

e.g.:  COM_NEWSFEEDS_FIELD_SHOW_FEED_IMAGE_LABEL is not defined.

Just wondering if I simply need to edit something minor to get it to work again.

Probably could just disable it for that site since I am not using it, and maybe when I update to a newer version of Joomla it'll fix itself ?

/sds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using it then don't bother - it'll take you an hour or so to resolve this completely and you won't even use it. I suggest your re-uninstall it again.

A Joomla update will most likely not get it back (just so you know).

I personally think it's a good idea to uninstall extensions (even core extensions) that are not being used.

Comment: Thanks.  I did finally get it restored, but it probably wasn't worth the time.